# Is there an automation tool or technique that will allow me to read the contents of an MFC Grid Control

Tags: mfc, pywinauto

I'm trying to write a program which will automate user function on an old C++ application for which we do not have the source code. At the moment I am using PyWinAuto, a library which seems to be able to simulate a wide range of user actions, however I have hit a blocker:

One part of the application which contains information we need is implemented with an MFC Grid Control(MFCGridCtrl). I can get a reference to the control itself, but not to the individual rows and columns of the grid.

Is there any way for me to get a reference to the rows, or more specifically the objects in each row?

What I actually want to do is iterate over each row and and read certain values from cells in each row. The values I need are simple things, for example Text and a Check-box.

While PyWinAuto is what I'm using now, I'm open to using any kind of tool which might help me access this control. One of the concerns I have had is that this may be impossible: I have read in documentation provided by TestComplete that MFCGridControls do not provide have a model with externally visible methods unless the application is compiled with debug symbols.

Unfortunately we don't have the source code, so recompiling is not an option!

I'm open to literally any suggestions regarding how we might automate this software. It can be based on any technology - not just Python.

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/43386-interaction-with-an-mfcgridctrl-object/

Comment: Neither `MFCGridCtrl` nor `MFCGridControl` are standard MFC controls. They appear to be 3rd-party controls. Your only hope to get at the information you need is to use [UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). You can use the [Inspect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to verify whether the control implements those interfaces. pywinauto can be configured to use the UI Automation backend (`backend="uia"`). If that doesn't work, there's little hope to solve this, irrespective of the technology.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Sorry for delay in response. I did give a try with your solutions but no luck for me.